# Codeigniter: Error - call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently, I want to add new php file in view folder. But, when I add that file, the error display as below even I copied code from the existing file:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

> Line Number: 532
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/spezerco/public_html/orlins/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

I already tried look up on the function I created in model and the load code ( $this->loadViews("plan", $this->global, $data, NULL);) but i still can't figure out the problem.

so here is the code:

in CodeIgniter.php line 532:
call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), $params);

in index.php line 315:
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: Well, instead of posting all these error messages it would be helpful to post the relevant controller/model code that has caused these errors.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem when I deployed my local project to InfinityFree hosting. Anyone figured out what the problem is?